# ¿Como crear objetos que son de una subclase? JAVA

Tags: java

Hola estoy intentando crear objetos que pertencen a una subclase, pero antes de estos esta subclase hereda de una clase abstracta, esta esuna parte de mi diagrama de clases de mi proyecto[image: Diagrama de clases de mi proyeto]

Ademas tengo mi proyecto divido en dos paquetes, en la carpeta model tengo una clase controladora en la cual he definido el siguiente metodo.

```
public String createAnewSeason(String productName, int scheduledEpisodes,
    int publishedEpisodes, String pathTrailer){
    String out = "";
    boolean flag = false;

    for(int i = 0; i<products.length;i++){
        if(products[i] != null){
            if(products[i].getProductName().equals(productName)){
                products[i].addSeason(scheduledEpisodes,publishedEpisodes, pathTrailer);
                out = "The new season has been created";
            }
            else{
                out = "The serie does not exist";
            }
        }

    }
    return out;
```

ademas en la clase serie he definido el seguiente metodo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero a la hora de compilar mi codigo me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me podria ayudar a identificar que estoy haciendo mal o donde debo poner dichos metodos?

Comment: Dónde define products?

Comment: y donde esta el metodo addSeason?

Comment: Hola ya lo pude solucionar me faltaba poner el cast para identificar que ese metodo pertenecía a la clase serie